# Finding a point pattern in a image with tensorflow

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow

Currently I have the problem that I want to find a specific pattern in a image. The target I would like to get from tensorflow is
[x,y,angle]. x and y are the coordinates of a location of a point inside the pattern. angle is the angle of how it is rotated in the image 0-359° (in radian).

Also the pattern changes not basically, but depending on where it is because the images is created from a 2D Laser scanner. So sometimes you see parts of it sometimes not.

Input data is a 400x400 black and white image where white is a laser scanner point and black is free space

What kind a problem is that? Classification? But how do I get the position where it is found in a image? Actually I think it is a bit the same like the one Google uses for finding things in images.

I actually was modifying the Deep MNIST example but somehow I do not get to a point where I get something useful out of it.

Has anybody an idea, which could point me to the right direction?

Regards,

Christian

Answer (score 0):

Your problem - as from your given description - seems to be solvable with traditional computer vision approaches. The problem itself would be a detection problem.

Rather than a machine learning algorithm, you need a systematic approach breaking this problem down into smaller problems:

At first you need to detect your points (I assume you have two points). Here you can apply CV detection algorithms - is it even a different color, maybe a color filter might be enough to detect the point positions.

With your two point positions and a bit of geometry you can then calculate the distance and the angle between the line the two points span and the image border.

Doing this with an ML model may be hard without any expertise, because you are basically interfering with the built in mechanisms to augment data (ML software will automatically rotate and scale input images randomly).

Even then, I think may be for the detection of the points, if all the simple methods fail, you may detect them with machine learning and then do the geometric relations. But trying to do end 2 end learning with this problem seems to be overkill.